# Sending multiple emails using UTL_SMTP in oracle

Tags: oracle, email, smtp

I am trying to write a procedure which send emails from Oracle DB using UTL_SMTP functions. Its working fine if I am only sending one email address but if I am passing multiple emails as comma or semicollon(;), its failling with error like

```
ORA-29277: invalid SMTP operation
ORA-29279: SMTP permanent error: 501 5.1.3 Invalid address
```

I am writing the statement like :- where P_ALERT_DESTINATION is a variable which is having multiple emails id.

```
UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(L_MAIL_CONN, 'To: ' || P_ALERT_DESTINATION || UTL_TCP.CRLF);
```

Comment: Can someone please suggest me how to write this variable values in a cursor and use that later in a loop to fetch all values in TO section of email.

Comment: Did my solution worked?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to loop all email addresses and make that procedure call to each one.
Pseudo code:

```
for all_addresses loop
  UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(L_MAIL_CONN, 'To: ' || one_address|| UTL_TCP.CRLF)
end loop;
```

**Edited:**
Here you go, this should work:

```
declare
  cursor split_cursor(p_to in varchar2) is
  select regexp_substr(p_to, '[^,]+', 1, level) email_address
    from dual
  connect by regexp_substr(p_to, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null;
begin

  for i in split_cursor(P_ALERT_DESTINATION) loop
    UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(L_MAIL_CONN, 'To: ' || i.email_address|| UTL_TCP.CRLF);
  end loop;

end;
```

You should also remove all spaces if the variable contains those.

Comment: Hello, in my case P_ALERT_DESTINATION variable receive a list of email IDS like a@aa.com,b@aa.com,c@aa.com,d@aa.com  - we dont have any control on list as these values are coming from a DB tables.  could you please tell me how exactly I can code this.

Comment: I can help you later but do not have time now to test my code. But you only need to split that variable and make procedure call for each email address individually.